# Why poetry add git+https://github.com/blnkoff/foo-project.git installs package to venv/src

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I've created my python package in GitHub. I have no setup.py there , but have pyproject.toml with specified build system poetry.

In other project I use command for installing that package:

```
poetry add git+https://github.com/blnkoff/foo-project.git
```

My virtual environment folder structure before installing this package:

```
venv/
├─ lib/
├─ bin/
```

My virtual environment folder structure after installing this package:

```
venv/
├─ bin/
├─ lib/
│  ├─ foo_project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ foo_project/
```

Why this command create src folder in venv? It must do not do that.
If I use pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/blnkoff/foo-project.git
```

It will't do that.

How can I resolve this issue, so that with command

```
poetry add git+https://github.com/blnkoff/foo-project.git
```

package will be installed only to venv/lib, without installing to venv/src?

It should be not an option of command, because other packages from GitHub can contain other GitHub packages, that are to be not installed to venv/src

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Could you clarify why it's a problem for you? `$VENV/src` is the standard location for VCS dependency source trees. Pip uses it as well if you use `pip install -e git+...`. poetry needs to keep a copy of the VCS repo around to avoid having to re-clone it every time your update the dependencies.

Comment: It adds additional weight to the virtual environment. How can I avoid this cloning to src?